# Numerar registros de una consulta en MySQL (alternativa a variables definidas por el usuario)

Tags: mysql, sql

Dentro del gestor de bases de datos de MySQL tengo una tabla de la cual hago un `SELECT` general y quiero que me liste con un número incremental todos los registros;puedo hacerlo originalmente con una variable definida por el usuario del modo siguiente:

```
SET @counter = 0;

SELECT (@counter := @counter + 1) AS NP, name, email FROM profiles;
```

> Es importante mencionar que para que la variable `counter` vaya
>   incrementando el valor se necesita la sintáxis `:=` de lo contrario si
>   solo se usa el símbolo de `=` sin importar cuantos registros existan
>   se va a mantener el mismo valor declarado al inicio.

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente

```
+------+--------------+------------------+
| NP   | name         | email            |
+------+--------------+------------------+
|    1 | dfsdfsf      | dsfdsfsf         |
|    2 | alfa         | mail@mail.com    |
|    3 | danielo      | mail@mail.com    |
|    4 | ortega   oga | mail@mail.com    |
|    5 | diana        | mail@mail.com    |
|    6 | elena        | mail@mail.com    |
|    7 | gonzalo      | mail@mail.com    |
|    8 | jorge        | mail@mail.com    |
|    9 | mendez       | mail@mail.com    |
|   10 | pedro        | mail@mail.com    |
|   11 | arnoldo      | mail@mail.com    |
+------+--------------+------------------+
```

Sin embargo no deseo depender de esta opción ya que necesito saber como hacerlo con una `window function()` para evitar estar declarando variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dentro de las características de MySQL 8 **(en versiones anteriores no existe la posibilidad de usar Window Functions)** podemos encontrar las **window functions**, como caso específico:

1. **row_number()** la cual me ayudará a generar de manera secuencial e incremental un registro numérico partiendo del 1 y aumentando en 1

El código anterior entonces se podría reescribir de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS NP, name, email
FROM profiles;
```

El resultado quedaría del modo siguiente

```
+------+--------------+------------------+
| NP   | name         | email            |
+------+--------------+------------------+
|    1 | dfsdfsf      | dsfdsfsf         |
|    2 | alfa         | mail@mail.com    |
|    3 | danielo      | mail@mail.com    |
|    4 | ortega   oga | mail@mail.com    |
|    5 | diana        | mail@mail.com    |
|    6 | elena        | mail@mail.com    |
|    7 | gonzalo      | mail@mail.com    |
|    8 | jorge        | mail@mail.com    |
|    9 | mendez       | mail@mail.com    |
|   10 | pedro        | mail@mail.com    |
|   11 | arnoldo      | mail@mail.com    |
+------+--------------+------------------+
```

**Observaciones:**

> 1. No dependo de la creación de una variable de sesión
> 2. `row_number()` necesita a su vez trabajar con la sentencia `OVER` para que de esta manera se le indique sobre que columna se desea hacer
>      el ordenamiento, en este caso se trabaja sobre la columna `name`
> 3. También le podemos colocar un alias a `row_number()` para mejorar su lectura
> 4. El ordenamiento que hace `OVER` es de tipo `ascendente` por defecto salvo que se le indique lo contrario