# Volver a ordenar numéricamente el campo ID (auto incrementado) de una tabla de base de datos MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

No se como volver a numerar las filas en orden por el campo ID, ya que he ido borrado algunas.
[image: volver a ordenar por numero, del 1 al 9]

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE nombretabla.....? ";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "Re-ordered successfully";
} else {
    echo "none reorder: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema de que no sean consecutivas? ¿Existen registros relacionados en otras tablas? Desde mi punto de vista es un "esfuerzo" innecesario. PD: lo mas facil y rápido seria borrar la columna y crearla de nuevo SIEMPRE Y CUANDO no existan registros relacionados.

Comment: Necessito que a medida que las voy borrando el campo id se renumere. Ya que tenfo un contador de rows que las selecciona segun la id, Tiene que coicidir el numero de filas con el numero de id. Se puede hacer?

Comment: Podes numerar las filas sin tener que forzar que cohicidan con el `id` del registro. ¿Pensaste que debería pasar si se **cambia el orden en que se muestran** los registros? Supone que mañana necesitas mostrarlos por `name ASC`

Comment: [Acá dejo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/198145/16597) una opción que puede que te sirva

Comment: No me funciona, lo que tengo que cambiar son los numeros en el campo ID, cada vez que elimino una fila debo voler redefinir los valores de id  de 1 hasta el ultimo